# Отобразить множество различных объектов, обладающих одинаковыми свойствами, Swing

Tags: java, swing

Как, используя Swing, можно создать на панели множество объектов, допустим, кругов, каждый из которых будет обладать одинаковыми методами (движение, удаление, взаимодействие), но при этом разными характеристиками (цвет / размер) ? Как их хранить и обрабатывать?

Comment: Что вы конкретно хотите сделать? В чём проблема?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вас писал) Создается полотно, на полотне распологаются два JLabel (что угодно) и идет управление X Y по таймеру (Можно даже поставить слушатели на клавиатуру и управлять ими).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaApplication22 {
    static JLabel A = null;
    static int Ax = 0; //КОРДИНАТЫ
    static int Ay = 0; //КОРДИНАТЫ

    static JLabel B = null;
    static int Bx = 0; //КОРДИНАТЫ
    static int By = 40; //КОРДИНАТЫ

    static JLabel e = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("TEST");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        e = new JLabel("3");

        A = new JLabel("A");
        A.setSize(200, 200);
        A.setBackground(Color.red);
        A.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        B = new JLabel("B");
        B.setSize(200, 200);
        //
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setLayout(null); //МЫ НЕ БУДЕМ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ МЕНЕДЖЕРЫ КОМПОНОВКИ А ПРОСТО БУДЕМ ВРУЧНУЮ УПРАВЛЯТЬ X Y, что за менеджеры загляните туда http://www.quizful.net/post/swing-layout-managers



        Dimension size = panel.getPreferredSize();  //МЫ РАБОТАЕМ В ПРЕДЕЛАХ ПАНЕЛИ УЗНАЕМ ЕЁ КОНЕЧНУЮ ШИРИНУ И ВЫШИНУ, я здесь этого не описывал но думаю вы додумаетесь как его использовать

        A.setBounds(Ax,Ay , A.getWidth(), A.getHeight()); //УСТАНАВЛИВАЕМ КОРДИНАТЫ НАЧАЛЬНЫЕ
        B.setBounds(Bx,By , B.getWidth(), B.getHeight()); 

        //
        panel.add(A); //ДОБАВИМ НА ПАНЕЛЬ НАШУ НАДПИСЬ (МОЖНО НЕ НАДПИСЬ А НАПРИМЕР КАРТИНКУ, IMAGEICON, И ТД
        panel.add(B);
        //

        //



        //ПО ДРУГОМУ Я НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК ДОБАВИТЬ ПАНЕЛЬ НА ФРЕЙМ, ДОБАВЛЯЕМ ЧЕРЕЗ МЕНЕДЖЕР КОМПАНОВКИ
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup() //Создаем паралель
            .addComponent(panel, 500,500,500) //ФИКСИРУЕМ РАЗМЕР ПОЛОТНА, ЭТО ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬ ТОЕСТЬ 500 ПО ШИРИНЕ 
            .addComponent(e)

        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(panel, 500,500,500)
            .addComponent(e)    

        );
        frame.setSize(400, 500);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);



        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Ax = Ax + 50;
                By = By + 50;
                A.setBounds(Ax,Ay , A.getWidth(), A.getHeight()); //УСТАНАВЛИВАЕМ КОРДИНАТЫ НАЧАЛЬНЫЕ
                B.setBounds(Bx,By , B.getWidth(), B.getHeight()); 

                e.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(e.getText())+1));
            }
        };
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(task, 500, 1200); //500 подождать прежде чем начать, 1200 повторятся
    }

}
```