# Движение изображения Java

Tags: java, swing

Хочу создать анимацию движения иконки поезда, но все никак не могу понять как это сделать. С фигурами получилось с картинкой - нет, подскажите.

```
public class TrainMoveAnimation extends JPanel implements Runnable {

public static final String NAME = "Title Game";
public static final int WIDTH = 490;
public static final int HEIGHT = 450;
private Image image;
private Graphics2D g2;

public TrainMoveAnimation() {
    loadImage();
    new Thread(this).start();
}

private void loadImage() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("F://train.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TrainMoveAnimation game = new TrainMoveAnimation();
    game.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void run() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (g2 != null) {
            g2.drawImage(image, x, 0, null);
            super.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            x += 25;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Может вам это поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477053/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-swin/477074#477074 там описывается движение двух JLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько замечаний:

Перенесите координаты изображения в поля `TrainMoveAnimation` (еще можно завести отдельный класс `Train` в который потом сложить все свойства поезда). Перерисовку окна может вызвать не только ваш код, но и внешние события (восстановление окна из свернутого состояния, например), поэтому код `paint` должен знать, где рисовать поезд.

В Swing обычно рисуют содержимое компонента не в `paint`, а в `paintComponent`. Кроме рисования самого компонента `paint` вызывает еще отрисовку его детей и рамки.

```
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println( System.identityHashCode( g ) );
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
}
```

Сохранять `Graphics` в поле нет смысла, т.к. при каждой перерисовке вам дадут порисовать на новом.

Передавать кому-то ссылку на текущий объект (`this`) в конструкторе - опасно. Особенно в другой поток. Даже если делать это, как у вас, в последней строке конструктора. Во-первых, нет гарантий, что ВМ не поменяет порядок операций для оптимизации. Во-вторых, если вы будете наследовать от такого класса, код конструктора потомка точно будет выполнен после передачи ссылки, и в многопоточной программе другой поток может работать с частично инициализированным объектом.

Чтобы избежать проблем с многопоточностью, для анимации можно использовать `javax.swing.Timer`. После запуска он будет с заданной периодичностью вызывать `actionPerformed` у переданного объекта в EDT.

```
public void start() {
    javax.swing.Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            nextStep();
        }
    } );
    timer.start();
}

private void nextStep() {
    x += 25;
    repaint();
}
```

Если нужно останавливать анимацию, сохраните таймер, как поле `TrainMoveAnimation`. После создания всех объектов, вызовите `game.start()`, чтобы запустить анимаци. Метод `run` и интерфейс `Runnable` можно убрать.